# How can I hide a functions signature(arguments) ) in doxygen?

Tags: function, doxygen, signature

I need to hide all functions signatures in doxygen.
any idea how i can do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please show some code and results as well the results you got and would like to have. Furthermore specify the computer language you are using and the version of doxygen.

Comment: Hi ,
the language is C/C++  and i would like to hide the function signature in definition.
example : 
int test_code(int x,int y);

I would like that doxygen will not show the signature of the function test_code ((int x,int y)).
I dont want to completly expose my code and would like to hide teh function signature.

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: After some time revisiting. It is still a bit unclear what you want but I think you probably should have a look at the doxygen commands like `\if` and `\cond`